# Php if and else

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm trying to make this code work but I don't know why it won't. Basically I want it to display a name if the nickname column in the database is null. And if it's not null it should display the nickname. Also I'm somewhat noob so keep that in mind when responding.

```
$namn = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM Horseinfo WHERE name = '$somevariable'");
$nicknamn = mysql_query("SELECT nickname FROM Horseinfo WHERE name = '$somevariable'");

<? $row = mysql_fetch_array($nicknamn,$namn); 
                if(is_null($nicknamn)) {?>
                <div style='font-size:18px; padding-bottom:3px; margin-top:0px;'>records for <? echo $row['name'];?></div>
            <?} else {?>
                <div style='font-size:18px; padding-bottom:3px; margin-top:0px;'>records for <? echo $row['nickname'];?></div>
            <?}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on assumption I would say that your `nickname` column does not contain a database NULL value, rather it would be an empty string instead (this totally depends on the routine filling the `Horseinfo` table). You also only need one SQL query to fetch both `name` and `nickname`.

My suggestion would be to use [empty()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.empty.php) instead:

```
// try to use mysqli_* instead of mysql_* functions, mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be a database connection resource
$res = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT name, nickname FROM Horseinfo WHERE name = '$somevariable'");
if ($res && mysqli_num_rows($res)>0) {
  $row = mysqli_fetch_row($res); 
  $horseName= empty($row['nickname']) ? $row['name'] : $row['nickname'];
  ?>
  <div style='font-size:18px; padding-bottom:3px; margin-top:0px;'>records for <? echo horseName;?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: thing is I have null in the DB: http://i.imgur.com/yTkVzpt.png as the picture shows. I tried your suggestion but for some reason it doesn't work at all. It makes the whole page go blank.

Comment: I updated the code, could you also add `ini_set("display_errors", "1");` and `error_reporting("E_ALL");` somewhere at the start of your script so we don't miss any errors?

Comment: The site is no longer blank but following code <div style='font-size:18px; padding-bottom:3px; margin-top:0px;'>records for <? echo $horseName;?></div> doesn't show up at all. I'm not getting any errors either.

Comment: Seems short open tags are disabled in php.ini. Exchange <? with <?php and see if that works.

Comment: I tried that now but nothing changed. Since the entire <div> doesn't show up it's like its not in the code even if it is.

Comment: Could you post the code you are currently using on [PhpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/)?

Comment: Some remarks first: get rid of the tons of SQL queries, most of them can be combined or are simply obsolete. Leave a blank space between opening <? and <?php to avoid errors, enable MySQLi and change your code to use it rather than `mysql_*`. I updated the relevant part of the code, try this instead: http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/27e091e61ed348798c78